# How do random number generators in calculators work?

Tags: calculator, random-number

I have a TI-30xIIs scientific calculator. I was playing around with some of the functions, and I discovered it had a random number generator. I became curious as to how it worked. My first thought was that it used avalanche noise or noise generated by the diodes in the solar panel, but then I realized that they could be using some sort of algorithm like a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)

Comment: There probably isn't any way to know, since the processor is proprietary an specific to TI's calculators and does not have a manual or documentation.

Comment: The 1st Apple ][e computers just used a feedback XOR generator that was very repetitive in a 2k array and it wasn't even maximal length, so we had to create a new seed from the time at random intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual, the random number is generated from a seed, and a new seed is generated after a random number is generated. Also the random number seed is user selectable to control sequences of random numbers.

All this gives information that it is a simple deterministic pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), something like a linear congruent generator (LCG), or a linear feedback shift register (LFSR).

Given the fact that this random generation must be repeatable, it makes sense to simply use pseudo-random generation instead of other kinds of randomness, even if it is tempting to use entropy from some sources like battery voltage level, timestamps of button press and release events, etc.

It seems that someone has (almost) figured the algorithm for the exact same calculator and has a [webpage about it on github](https://theusaf.github.io/TI30XCalc/) to calculate next numbers given the seed value.

Looking at the code, it's an LCG which uses numbers 40014 and 2147483563, of which the latter is a prime. These numbers seem to be quite popular due to a paper by L'Ecuyer on implementing LCGs, as [discussed on United-TI Archives](https://www.cemetech.net/projects/uti/viewtopic.php?t=6883&start=32).

Comment: thanks so much! could you possibly provide a link to the manual you were talking about? i could seem to find it when i searched...

Comment: An LCG of that size is more complex than I'd have thought, for the use case, I must plainly admit. (I'm going for wild speculation here, but they might have had that IP for a different product already and using it was cheaper/less risky than to go for something simpler, maybe) A well-deserved upvote for all the insight this gives!

Comment: @cosmofm Manuals are usually found on manufacturer product or support pages. I don't have a link any more. Besides if I link to one this today, the link might stop working tomorrow. Like for any manual, search for "(manufacturer name) (device model) manual pdf".

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible to know without much testing, but, two general options

1. good (reliable!) physical random number generation is great, but expensive to achieve, usually. (this has changed in recent years, with a couple modern microcontrollers shipping such units – but it's still a feature you pay for)
2. Pseudo-Random number generators give you a deterministic sequence of numbers that look very random (i.e. don't seem correlated, are close to uniformly distributed etc), and is very different for different initializations ("seeds")

The Mersenne Twister is a good pseudo-random number generator, but it's a memory- and power-hungry beast. Since nobody could push the "random" button multiple billion times, the quality of pseudorandom numbers generated does nearly not matter at all.

So, my guess is this is a very "cheap" PRNG, quite possibly just a linear-feedback shift register, or a very small multi-recursive combinations of similar things. To not actually give you the same sequence every time, the internal state might be initialized and changed by not-extremely-random-but-still-better-than-nothing sources of physical entropy like the drift between the LCD bias oscillator and the processor core clock, or the number of ringing on keypresses.